# Jquery .click() causes code to break

Tags: javascript, jquery

Adding this line of code `$("#locate-me-button").click(loadLocation());` breaks my entire JavaScript code file even if I don't click the `#locate-me-button` element. When this line is commented out the entire file works perfectly again. Why would that be?

Comment: People would be able to help you more effectively if you posted the relevant code to go along with your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking the function as passing its return value to event handler, just pass the function reference to `.click()`

```
$("#locate-me-button").click(loadLocation);
                                       //^ () is removed
```

Answer (score 1):

The another way (at least for case that you have parameter):

```
$("#locate-me-button").click(function(){
     loadLocation();
 });
```